# Sibling subview does not receive touches in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, touchesbegan, uiresponder

I have a view (`parent`) with two subviews, one on top (`topChild`) of the other (`bottomChild`).

If I tap on the screen only `topChild` and `parent` receive the touch event.

What should I change to propagate the touch event to `bottomChild` as well?

The code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MYView* parent = [[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    parent.tag = 3;
    parent.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    MYView* bottomChild = [[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
    bottomChild.tag = 2;
    bottomChild.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [parent addSubview:bottomChild];

    MYView* topChild = [[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    topChild.tag = 1;
    topChild.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [parent addSubview:topChild];
    [self.view addSubview:parent];
}
```

Where `MYView` is a subclass of `UIView` that only logs `touchesBegan`.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%d", self.tag);
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The result:

[image]

Touching the green area produces the following log:

```
TouchTest[25062:f803] 1
TouchTest[25062:f803] 3
```

My first idea was to make `parent` propagate all the `touchesSomething` calls to its children but **(A)** I suspect there might be an easier solution and **(B)** I don't know which child sent the event to parent, and sending `touchesSomething` messages twice to the same view might cause shenanigans.

After asking the question I've found this [post](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=74) that suggests to override `hitTest` to change the view that receives the touches. I will try this approach and update the question if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting problem you have that is probably something best addressed through a rethink of the way you have things structured. But to make it work the way you suggest you need to catch the touch event in the current top view, pass it to the parent and then propagate it down through all subviews of the parent view. To make this work you would need the `touchesBegan:` (or whatever other method you use to intercept the touch) to do nothing in all the views, doing the action only in the method called by the parent view.

Which is really another way of saying don't handle touches in the views, catch them but notify the parent view view and then call subview methods as required to cause the effect you want.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // Do nothing, parent view calls my parentNotifiedTouchesBegan method
    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) parentNotifiedTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // Act on the touch here just as my sibling views are doing
}
```

Note I changed `super` to `self.superview` in that code. You may or may not also want to call `super`'s method depending on what you are doing, and the place to call that may be in `parentNotifiedTouchesBegan`.

You can know which subView sent the event of course, just use a custom method to notify the superview instead of calling its `touchesBegan:`. Use a `self` argument.

Comment: Thanks Adam! Would this solution be compatible with gesture recognizers? At first glance it looks like I will have to reimplement the wheel if I go this route.

Comment: And I would very much like to re-structure things, but I don't see how in my case. topChild has transparency, both topChild and bottomChild can "move" (thus topChild cannot be a subview of bottomChild), and both need to respond to touches.

Comment: It should be possible, you would just be passing the gestureRecognizer object received by the callback up to the parent rather than a simple touch. At least in the project I have handy this would work for UIPinchGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Now I'm thinking you don't need to catch events in subviews at all, in fact you can disable interaction so that the base view gets everything. No need to do the notification step. Just have base view catch and interpret everything and cause the views to act. You should be able to isolate the views that should get the event by comparing the point (- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view) to the subview's frames (CGRectContainsPoint).

Comment: That was what I was trying now! That said, I find it very strange that this has to be done "manually". I would imagine this is a pretty common problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the touches on the children then set

```
bottomChild.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
topChild.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```